# Empty element in List causing Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range

Tags: java, list, exception, indexing, indexoutofboundsexception

I am working with a CSV file that looks like this 
https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/photo/115135191238195349859/6559552907258825106

as you can see in the coloum "date_sold" there are gaps

I am trying to shorten the dates to just the month (the first two ints of the whole date with this method:

```
public static void getTotalSales(){

    int w = 0; 
    while (w < date_sold.size()){ 
// if the current element is smaller than the size of the 
        if((date_sold.get(w)) != "" ){ 
// if the element in the array is empty (might be the problem)
      date_sold.set(w,((date_sold.get(w)).substring(0,2)));
// trim the string at the element to two characters
     }
    w = w + 1;
  }
System.out.println(date_sold);
}
```

This prints out working for the first element from "date_sold" to "da" 
but then I get a

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range
```

I would like to skip over empty elements but not get rid of them as the indexing of empty elements is important to me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java)

Comment: that is not my problem

Comment: `date_sold.get(w)) != ""  `

Comment: you are confusing me, i still get error

Comment: But you are comparing strings with `!=`, which is invalid. Also, you should be checking that the `length()` is at least 2 before doing the `substring`. You might also want to `trim()` the string.

Comment: `date_sold.get(w)).substring(0,2)` requires your string length is at least 2.

Comment: how should I compare them please @DavidConrad

Comment: `if (!date_sold.get(w).equals(""))` you can find this in any introductory Java tutorial. But what you really want is `if (date_sold.get(w).length() >= 2)`

Comment: @DavidConrad i dont know what i am doing wrong https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/photo/115135191238195349859/6560498045248873010

Comment: I don't either. Are you getting an exception? The wrong answer? If you're trying to extract the month from dates like "10/30/2017" and "5/16/2017" then taking the first two characters obviously won't work since the month isn't always two characters.

Comment: I didnt think about that :(

Comment: A couple of suggestions: `date.split("/")` will split it into a `String[]` on the slashes. The month will be in entry `0`. Or `date.indexOf("/")` will find the offset of the first slash, or `-1` if there isn't one. That index can then be used in a `substring`.

Comment: yes that sounds very promising, thank you for your time good sir